# Determining max width available for Code 128 barcode

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner, barcode-printing

I'm looking for some sort of formula available to determine how much data I can fit on a Code 128 barcode that is no larger than a given width. The use case is a wristband that has a barcode printed on it.

Is there a minimum size required for the smallest bar for everything to be visible? Are there size ratios available anywhere (i.e. "Z takes up x times more space than 0")? I see that Code 128 supports compression of strings on numbers. More data is taken away by eliminating alpha characters, but do I end up getting more data in the same width by doing so?

EDIT: Going with that there is compression for number strings, the solution was to just test out 10, 12, 15, etc character strings. We decided to go with 12 as this is way more than enough for our use and scans very easily on a 1-inch wristband with leaving 10% on each side open. I'm still interested in the info requested though if anyone has insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All characters are equal relative width. Code 128C allows you to fit two numbers into a single character, but if you need to mix and match numbers and letters, you'll need to consistently have two or more pairs of numbers consecutive to make the added burden of the switch character worthwhile.

After a certain height, the vertical dimension does not matter, depending on the scanner.

The width of a character is directly proportional to its scanability and dependent upon the generator software, hardware and print media.

I measure density in characters per inch and with an inkjet printer I can get about 15½ characters per scannable inch. Packing them any denser and I suspect I would need a better printer and maybe a better scanner.

Here is a 40 character string encoded in Code128B at 15.6 cpi (43 characters including start, check and stop).

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/ASL/AADeAAAA/gAAAAIAAAD+AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAh6QEAZKdo54AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAA/wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAcjEDAghkmFUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAA/wAAAAAAAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAckoDA0TA9lYAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASVICA62zYxMAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAAAAAAAAQAAAP8AAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAbjEDAjQrOn0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAARTkCAqx1lb4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASVICA62zYxMAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUU4CA1nljTgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAAAAAAAAQAAAP8AAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAbkoDA3iPVH4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAD/AAAAAAAAAAEAAAD/AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAZjUDAmZGozoAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAARTkCAqx1lb4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAAAAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASU4CA+16cNAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUU4CA1nljTgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAAAAAAAP8AAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAbk4DAxdhexwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAAAAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASU4CA+16cNAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAD/AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAajUDAt82atYAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAajkDAr7LFAwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAD/AAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATU4CA7CME0sAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAD/AAAAAQAAAAAAAAD/AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAZjkDAtle3bIAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAP8AAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAARVICA/z3WM0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/ASL/AADeAAAA/gAAAAIAAAD+AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAh6QEAZKdo54AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAbjUDAlvFFR8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAARTkCAqx1lb4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAD/AAAAAQAAAAAAAAD/AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAZjkDAtle3bIAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAA/wAAAAAAAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAckoDA0TA9lYAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASVICA62zYxMAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAAAAAAAAQAAAP8AAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAbjEDAjQrOn0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAARTkCAqx1lb4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASVICA62zYxMAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUU4CA1nljTgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAAAAAAAAQAAAP8AAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAbkoDA3iPVH4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAD/AAAAAAAAAAEAAAD/AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAZjUDAmZGozoAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAARTkCAqx1lb4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAAAAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASU4CA+16cNAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUU4CA1nljTgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAAAAAAAP8AAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAbk4DAxdhexwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAAAAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASU4CA+16cNAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAD/AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAajUDAt82atYAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAajkDAr7LFAwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAD/AAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATU4CA7CME0sAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAD/AAAAAQAAAAAAAAD/AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAZjkDAtle3bIAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAP8AAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAARVICA/z3WM0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/ASL/AADeAAAA/gAAAAIAAAD+AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAh6QEAZKdo54AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAbjUDAlvFFR8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAARTkCAqx1lb4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAD/AAAAAQAAAAAAAAD/AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAZjkDAtle3bIAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAA/wAAAAAAAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAckoDA0TA9lYAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASVICA62zYxMAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAAAAAAAAQAAAP8AAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAbjEDAjQrOn0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAARTkCAqx1lb4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASVICA62zYxMAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUU4CA1nljTgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAAAAAAAAQAAAP8AAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAbkoDA3iPVH4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAD/AAAAAAAAAAEAAAD/AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAZjUDAmZGozoAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAARTkCAqx1lb4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAAAAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASU4CA+16cNAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUU4CA1nljTgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAAAAAAAP8AAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAbk4DAxdhexwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAAAAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASU4CA+16cNAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAD/AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAajUDAt82atYAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAajkDAr7LFAwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAD/AAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATU4CA7CME0sAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAD/AAAAAQAAAAAAAAD/AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAZjkDAtle3bIAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAP8AAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAARVICA/z3WM0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/ASL/AADeAAAA/gAAAAIAAAD+AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAh6QEAZKdo54AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAbjUDAlvFFR8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAARTkCAqx1lb4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAD/AAAAAQAAAAAAAAD/AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAZjkDAtle3bIAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAA/wAAAAAAAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAckoDA0TA9lYAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASVICA62zYxMAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAAAAAAAAQAAAP8AAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAbjEDAjQrOn0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAARTkCAqx1lb4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASVICA62zYxMAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUU4CA1nljTgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAAAAAAAAQAAAP8AAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAbkoDA3iPVH4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAD/AAAAAAAAAAEAAAD/AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAZjUDAmZGozoAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAARTkCAqx1lb4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAAAAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASU4CA+16cNAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUU4CA1nljTgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAAAAAAAP8AAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAbk4DAxdhexwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAAAAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASU4CA+16cNAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAD/AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAajUDAt82atYAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAajkDAr7LFAwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAD/AAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATU4CA7CME0sAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAD/AAAAAQAAAAAAAAD/AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAZjkDAtle3bIAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAP8AAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAARVICA/z3WM0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/ASL/AADeAAAA/gAAAAIAAAD+AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAh6QEAZKdo54AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAbjUDAlvFFR8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAARTkCAqx1lb4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAD/AAAAAQAAAAAAAAD/AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAZjkDAtle3bIAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAA/wAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAck4DAxY8F10AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUUoCA+juoggAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAD/AAAAAQAAAAAAAAD/AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAZjkDAtle3bIAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUU4CA1nljTgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAA/wAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAck4DAxY8F10AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="4" height="30">
```

Comment: Thank you, I ended up doing a trial and error route and settled on 12 characters. 15 was a little inconsistent scanning after leaving room for white space. 12 gives significantly more values than needed and was never difficult to scan

Comment: Did you end up using Code 128B or Code 128C?

Answer (score 0):

@Alex DeCamillo,

The ISO/IEC 15417 specification for the Code 128 symbology defines a formula to calculate the width which utilizes the number of characters, the width of the narrowest element and the required quiet zone to calculate the overall width. You can also use it with a constant width to calculate the required width of the minimum element and so forth.  Unfortunately, I was not able to find this formula documented outside of the specification, so I cannot share the formula without violating the terms of the specification, but you can get the spec here: https://www.iso.org/standard/43896.html

Terry Warwick, Microsoft

Comment: Thank you, it looks like this would be what I was hoping for but I cannot justify purchasing that paper for just curiosity. Trial and error was more than enough to find an appropriate width